# Mail sent "on behalf of" when using PHP Pear

Tags: php, email, pear

I am using PEAR to send mails from our server. However, some email clients (most importantly Gmail) will say "Mail received from nobody@server on behalf of John Doe". What causes this? Is this PHP or the server config itself?

With the headers I set:

> ```
> $headers["From"] = John Doe<johndoe@example.com>;
> $headers["Return-path"] = John Doe<johndoe@example.com>;
> $headers["Sender"] = John Doe<johndoe@example.com>;
> ```

However, when I look into the e-mail headers of the actual mail that is arrived, I see:

> ```
> Return-path: <nobody@server>
> Received: from nobody by server with local (Exim 4.69)
>   (envelope-from <nobody@server>)
>   id 1Thn0Y-0001yy; Tue, 25 Jan 2011 11:48:46 -0600
> From: John Doe<johndoe@example.com>
> Sender: Nobody <nobody@server>
> Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 11:48:46 -0600
> ```

So except for the FROM field, all other header settings are ignored...! What to do?

Comment: Those fields are presumably overriden by your servers mail daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is that the envelope headers are being generated by Exim.  You will need to change the configuration, or send differently to get around this.  With normal sendmail, there are a few simple commandline switches you specify, and I would imagine it is the same with Exim.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Changed it in EXIM and works all good now!